# C++: Incorrect result using str.find(str1) to find whether a string is a substring of another string

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to find whether a street name string is a substring of an intersection name: e.g. "Yonge St." is a substring of "Yonge St. & Dundas St.", which describes an intersection. I used str.find() for this, but when I tried to do the following test, the result is not what I intended:

[image] I think the second "Express" after the ampersand (the one before "lanes" in string `A`) is the reason causing `test` to be evaluated to be `true`, when in reality it should be `false`, because "Express" in A1 is different to A because of the "Collector". Is there another way to check whether a string is a **"continuous"** substring of a larger string?

My current idea is to separate the intersection name at ampersand into two half intersection names, and compare `A1` and `A2` with each of the half intersection name. That works, but I need to loop this segment for 10k+ times, so I don't think that's an efficient fix. Also, intersection names might have more than one "&" so that might generate mistakes.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Um... Your `A1` **is** a **continuous** substring of `A`. It is not clear what do you see as "wrong" with the result you obtained.

Comment: Like AnT said, it IS a substring that matches the second Highway 401 in A.  Are you trying to do some other, non-standard matching like "must match starting at position = 0 or at position +1 of ' & '"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find()` is working properly. A1 **is** a substring of A.

```
A: Highway 401 Eastbound Collector & Switchover to Highway 401 Eastbound Express lane
A1:                                                Highway 401 Eastbound Express lane
```

If you want to check if a string is a substring of another string at a specific position use the [`string::compare()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/?kw=string%3A%3Acompare) function. You can use a stringstream and `getline()` to seperate the string at the ampersand. Doing this 10k times should be no problem at all and it should run in less than a second. Dealing with multiple ampersands is a different problem though.

By the way, please post your code as actual code not an image next time.

Comment: `a.substr(pos,count)==b` is probably less efficient than `a.compare(pos,count,b)==0`.

Comment: I actually did not know about this function's ability to do substrings, thanks for letting me know about it. I will edit my answer.